# Error executing DDL using postgresql hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am currently using springboot and use spring data jpa, postgresql. I am trying to create table using hibernate in postgresql. I think i don't use any database keywords on my table. Can anyone help me?

This is my Product class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "products")
@Entity
public class ProductEntity {

@Id
private UUID productID;
private String productName;
private BigDecimal price;
private String description;
private double rating;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ProductStatus productStatus;

private int quantity;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ProductImageEntity> productImages;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    ProductEntity product = (ProductEntity) o;
    return productID.equals(product.productID);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(productID);
}
```

}

---

This is my ProductImage class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "product_images")
@Entity
public class ProductImageEntity {

@Id
private UUID productImageID;

private String imageName;
private String contentType;
private Long dataSize;
@Lob
private byte[] image;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
private ProductEntity product;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    ProductImageEntity that = (ProductImageEntity) o;
    return productImageID.equals(that.productImageID);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(productImageID);
}
```

}

---

This is the error log:

```
    Hibernate: create table "product_image" ("product_imageid" uuid not null, "content_type" varchar(255), "data_size" int8, "image" oid, "image_name" varchar(255), "product_id" uuid, primary key ("product_imageid"))
2022-10-10 20:59:40.622  WARN 30832 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table "product_image" ("product_imageid" uuid not null, "content_type" varchar(255), "data_size" int8, "image" oid, "image_name" varchar(255), "product_id" uuid, primary key ("product_imageid"))" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table "product_image" ("product_imageid" uuid not null, "content_type" varchar(255), "data_size" int8, "image" oid, "image_name" varchar(255), "product_id" uuid, primary key ("product_imageid"))" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.online.shop.system.shop.service.ShopServiceApplication.main(ShopServiceApplication.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in
  Position: 14
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:329) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:315) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:286) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted

Hibernate: create table "products" ("productid" uuid not null, "description" varchar(255), "price" numeric(19, 2), "product_name" varchar(255), "product_status" varchar(255), "quantity" int4 not null, "rating" float8 not null, primary key ("productid"))
2022-10-10 20:59:40.624  WARN 30832 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table "products" ("productid" uuid not null, "description" varchar(255), "price" numeric(19, 2), "product_name" varchar(255), "product_status" varchar(255), "quantity" int4 not null, "rating" float8 not null, primary key ("productid"))" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table "products" ("productid" uuid not null, "description" varchar(255), "price" numeric(19, 2), "product_name" varchar(255), "product_status" varchar(255), "quantity" int4 not null, "rating" float8 not null, primary key ("productid"))" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.online.shop.system.shop.service.ShopServiceApplication.main(ShopServiceApplication.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in
  Position: 14
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:329) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:315) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:286) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted

Hibernate: alter table "product_image" add constraint "FK1rni4u2te2vo1poy7l4vehuss" foreign key ("product_id") references "products"
2022-10-10 20:59:40.626  WARN 30832 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table "product_image" add constraint "FK1rni4u2te2vo1poy7l4vehuss" foreign key ("product_id") references "products"" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table "product_image" add constraint "FK1rni4u2te2vo1poy7l4vehuss" foreign key ("product_id") references "products"" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:452) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.online.shop.system.shop.service.ShopServiceApplication.main(ShopServiceApplication.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "product_image" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:329) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:315) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:286) ~[postgresql-42.3.7.jar:42.3.7]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:5.6.11.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

---

This is my application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8180

spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    open-in-view: false
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        globally_quoted_identifiers: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: root
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    platform: postgres
    initialization-mode: always
```

Comment: *ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in*

Comment: Both entities have the same table name - @Table(name = "products")

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to create the schema on my postgres! @Jens

Comment: Side note, it is discouraged to use " ddl-auto: update" on production database, (You can still use it for unit test ) consider using flyway or liquibase to run database creation separatly (Spring boot modules also exists).